# How to fix wrong 404 for product pages in Magento 1.9.1.0 for recently viewed products

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, core, 404-page, bug

I experienced 404 pages for products after user session expiration. You can read the steps to reproduce the bug here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/541

What is the fix for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file `app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php` there is a function called `mergeVisitorProductIndex()`.  Instead of editing the core to change this function, you should override the resource Helper. This is a little different than overriding a standard helper but really only in the syntax of the config.xml.

First, create a small extension.

In `app/etc/modules` add a file called `George_Solution.xml`.

`George_Solution.xml` contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <George_Solution>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </George_Solution>
    </modules>
</config>
```

The `codePool` is "local" which means your module will be in "app/code/local" and  `George_Solution` means that it will be in "George/Solution".  Placing this file in "app/etc/modules" tell Magento where to look for your extension.

Next, create the file structure for your extension.  Go to "app/code/local" and create a folder called "George". Inside of George, create another folder called "Solution". The full path will be "app/code/local/George/Solution/".

Now create your `config.xml` file inside of "etc".  The full path will be "app/code/local/George/Solution/etc/config.xml".

`config.xml` contents:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <reports_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <helper_mysql4>George_Solution_Reports_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4</helper_mysql4>
                </rewrite>
            </reports_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Now that you have the Resource Helper extended, you can add your changed function.  You only need to add the function that you have changed something in.

Create the file structure: `George/Solution/Reports/Model/Resource/Helper`

In the `Helper` folder, create `Mysql4.php`

`Mysql4.php` contents:

```
<?php

class George_Solution_Reports_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4 extends Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4 {

    public function mergeVisitorProductIndex($mainTable, $data, $matchFields) {

        // Mage::log("My mergeVisitorProductIndex works!");

        // Old line: $result = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->insertOnDuplicate($mainTable, $data, array_keys($data));

        // Your new line:
        $result = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->insertOnDuplicate($mainTable, $data, $matchFields);

        return $result;

    }
}
```

The entire extension structure is:

```
app---etc---modules---George_Solution.xml
    |
    --code---local---George---Solution---etc---config.xml
                                       |
                                       --Reports-
                                                |-Model-
                                                        |-Resource-
                                                                   |-Helper---Mysql4.php
```

You can verify that this function is working by:

1. Turn on System logging
2. In the function `mergeVisitorProductIndex`, add a Mage::log() statement. I added one in the example above. Just uncomment the line.
3. Go to a product page and add a product to Compare.  Then navigate to another product and add it to Compare.
4. Go to var/log/system.log to see the message from the Mage::log().

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much Sean! I will send you an email.

Answer (score 1):

In file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php
```

Change line 48 from:

```
$result = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->insertOnDuplicate($mainTable, $data, array_keys($data));
```

to:

```
$result = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->insertOnDuplicate($mainTable, $data, $matchFields);
```

Comment: You should never edit the core. It is very easy to override a Helper. There's many resources out there explaining how to do this.

Comment: I am not a Magento developer per se. I know only how to make my own templates for frontend. I found a serious bug, spent a lot of time on it and published the solution. If you know how to fix that in a better way, could you please share?